# Equivalent for select tag with choose multiple options in struts

Tags: html, tags, html-select, struts

Hi I want to know the equivalent code in struts.

```
    <-select->
       <-option value="a"-> a <-/option->
       <-option value="b"-> b <-/option->
       <-option value="c"-> c <-/option->
       <-option value="d"-> d <-/option->
    <-/select->
```

we can represent the above in struts as

```
    <-sj:select-><-/sj:select->
```

Like that how to represent the following code that allows to select "multiple" values.

```
    <-select multiple="multiple"->
       <-option value="a"-> a <-/option->
       <-option value="b"-> b <-/option->
       <-option value="c"-> c <-/option->
       <-option value="d"-> d <-/option->
    <-/select->
```

I tried this. But no use.

```
    <-sj:select multiple="multiple"-><-/sj:select->
```

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tags [are documented](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.12/docs/select.html):

> multiple - required: false - default: false - evaluated: false - type: Boolean
>
> Creates a multiple select. The tag will pre-select multiple values if
>   the values are passed as an Array or a Collection(of appropriate
>   types) via the value attribute. If one of the keys equals one of the
>   values in the Collection or Array it wil be selected

Comment: Thank you man. I should have tried with multiple="true" rather than multiple="multiple". Next time will read the documentation b4 asking a question. Thanks again.